# Что это за строка (после использования express-generator)

Tags: node.js, express

После `npx express-generator .` создается папка `bin` в которой есть файлик `www`, в нем самой первой строкой идет `#!/usr/bin/env node`, что она означает и где об этом можно почитать?

Comment: Это, так называемая, шебанг (shebang) строка, она говорит системе кому передать файл для выполнения. #! - сами указатели что это shebang строка. usr/bin/env - путь к исп. файлу env, который, в свою очередь должен запустить node (если не ошибаюсь, env будет искать node в $PATH)

Comment: Не понял что она в итоге делает и какая от нее польза?

Comment: [Шебанг (Unix)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3_(Unix))